# Child container top margin pulls down parent top margin

Tags: html, css, parent-child, margin, positioning

I've got a background image in a parent container that covers the full screen width.

I want a child container centered within the parent which will contain some text and have a semi-transparent background color.

No matter how I try to set the top margin of the child, the parent container's top margin moves along with the child's as if the two top edges are "glued" together. The parent's margin follows the child's.

How can I make the contained element (.content) move down while keeping the top edge of the image fixed to the top of the page?

Thanks!

[BG image follows box's top margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tmVd.jpg)

```css
/* Header */

.hero {
  background: url('../images/hero_laptop_2.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
  height: 75vh;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.hero .content {
  border: solid black 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  height: 60%;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<header class="hero">
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar top">
    <h1 class="logo">
      <span class="text-primary"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i> IT</span>-Simplified</h1>
    <h1 id="navbar-phone">845-520-1115</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact-form">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h1>Welcome to IT-Simplified</h1>
    <p>We Provide COMPUTER SOLUTIONS... <br>Simply & Affordably.</p>
    <p id="call-us">Call Us: 845-520-1115</p>
    <!-- <a href="testimonials.html" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Testimonials</a> -->
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a position absolute or other positioning to the .hero .content class so that it will float on top of the background, independently of the parent container. Edit: In my solution below I have used `position: relative;`.

The z-index is irrelevant as the positioning take it out of the normal html flow context, so I removed it. Did a few other changes, take a look (use full screen, in the small snippet area below the content box doesn't display correctly).

Alternatively, you could try to make the .hero container `display: flex;` so you can position its children within it, but that doesn't seem to be practical here where you want the navigation on top and content below.

```css
/* Header */

.hero {
  background: url('https://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2017/11/autumn_fireball/17255671-1-eng-GB/Autumn_fireball.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
}

.hero .content {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  border: solid yellow 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<header class="hero">
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar top">
    <h1 class="logo">
      <span class="text-primary"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i> IT</span>-Simplified</h1>
    <h1 id="navbar-phone">845-520-1115</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact-form">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h1>Welcome to IT-Simplified</h1>
    <p>We Provide COMPUTER SOLUTIONS... <br>Simply & Affordably.</p>
    <p id="call-us">Call Us: 845-520-1115</p>
    <!-- <a href="testimonials.html" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Testimonials</a> -->
  </div>
</header>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Although I did get the .content box to position properly vertically, I can't seem to find a way to center it horizontally. If I position it absolutely, the margin set to "auto" don't work...the box just stays to the left. If I set absolute margins then of course the whole thing is not responsive.

Can you see a way to have the content box centered both vertically and horizontally while still being responsive?

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I positioned it relative, not absolute in the end. Absolute should work if you want to keep it relative to one of the sides with a percentage value as the margin. But `position: relative;` works fine here, and you get rid of the z-index at the same time. Edited the post to display the final result as presented by the full screen Stack snippet viewer.

Comment: P.S. Feel free to edit out the image and the phone number and company name from the post in case it's a real client/company.